# Why is $\pi_1 (S^n) = 0$ for $n \ge 2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, spheres, spherical-geometry

You can geometrically show why it's like that for $S^2$, as every curve based in a point $x$ can be retracted to that point $x$, so the fundamental group is trivial hence equal to the point $0$.

But why is it true for $S^3, S^4, ...$ too?

It would be great to find an intuitive, geometrical way to explain it to others. I don't need a formal mathematical proof, but just the intuition behind it and why it makes geometrically sense.

Comment: Van Kampen style: The two "fattened" hemispheres are contractible, and (important) when $n\ge2$, their intersection (around the equator) is path-connected.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Let's say I take $S^2$ here. I "flatten" the two hemispheres, and their intersection is the "ring around the equator" colloquially speaking, so it's $S^1$. But the fundamental group of $S^1$ is the set of integers, and not $0$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Or do you mean that because we get "that ring", it is contractible to a single point, and hence we've shown that the fundamental group of $S^2$ is equal to 0? (and for $S^3$ etc., we just have to apply this analogically? so in the case of $S^3$, the intersection of two flattened $S^3$ hemispheres is what exactly? It should be something which his retractable to a single point definitely?)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok, I see you wrote that it's "path-connected". Now I understand it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Every loop on $S^n$ with $n > 1$ is homotopic to a loop which is not surjective: its image lies in $S^n - \{x\}$ for some $x$. Since $S^n - \{x\}$ is homeomorphic to the contractible space $\mathbb{R}^n$, the loop is null-homotopic.

Answer (score 0):

Convince yourself inductively along the following lines. If I have a loop in $\mathbb{S}^{n}$, find a homotopy which contracts the loop to the equatorial sphere of a dimension lower. If the loop has become an interval, you're done, because this is contractible. If not, you can now continue the induction, forgetting the rest of the sphere and thinking now only within $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

Comment: Do you maybe have some images or something visual? I honestly can't even imagine an $S^3$ sphere as it's four dimensional.

Comment: @Student You can think of the $3$-sphere as $\mathbb R^3$ together with a single point at infinity that is the common limit of all rays through the origin. Alternatively, you can think of it as two solid balls (copies of $S^2$ together with their interiors) glued along the boundary $S^2$'s. These are both, of course, not *quite* visualizable, but they can help you get there.